# Is OpenAI ChatGPT available for Android?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-assistant

Is https://chat.openai.com available as an app for Android or even mobile in general?

When asking it directly, it claimed it can be installed as a service inside Google Assistance, but since I wasn't able to do it is that true? If so, can you provide screenshots?

[image: ChatGPT on mobile]

[image: Access ChatGPT with Google Assistant]

[image: Remove ChatGPT from Google Assistant]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OpenAI has published the official [ChatGPT Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.openai.chatgpt) on July 2023, but there's no integration with Google Assistant (yet).**

It is because:

- Saying "*talk to OpenAI Assistant*" on Google Assistant will do a web search as expected.
- Google Assistant doesn't have "Services", "Assistant", or "Apps" menu.
- *Google Assistant doesn't support 3rd-party assistance service.*
- <s>If there was such an OpenAI Assistant/ChatGPT on Android, even in the closed/private beta phase, then it would have been making news all over the place. Alas, there's none.</s> [ChatGPT for Android finally arrives next week](https://www.androidpolice.com/chatgpt-for-android/).

Please be aware of possible [hallucination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination_(artificial_intelligence)).